Opentelemetry override or ignore client span error status
Using Opentelemetry, I am generating spans in a trace, and I have an external library that does a HTTP GET call (to Elasticsearch). This span is marked as "client" and it is marked as "error" by the OTEL java agent that we are using. The library catches the exception and ignores it on certain http status codes, which we cannot control.
Is there something that can be done either to override that client error span status (with sdk or api) or to configure the agent so that it ignores these kind of span errors?



it is marked as "error" by our otel agent.

and

to configure the agent so that it ignores these kind of span errors?

What is this "our" agent you are referring to?

@SrikanthChekuri I have updated the question. We are using an opentelemetry java agent for auto instrumentation.

You can do this in the collector or look at processors, however I think you should state what you're trying achieve since it is correctly saying that span was an errored span.

thanks @MartinDotNet. Processors seem to do the job. Thanks for the answer.
Yes, I know that the span is marked correctly from the otel perspective, but because of the library behavior, we wanted a way to either override this span status, or ignore the span entirely. Thanks again for the answer, that was what I was looking for.

As Martin suggested, we ended up writing a processor in the OTel collector to ignore the span in this unwanted(by us) situation. There are quite a few processors available to choose from https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor
